# How should I remove special characters from data frame except space

Tags: python, regex, excel, pandas, dataframe

I am reading excel file (specific one sheet), it looks very much like this. I would like to remove all the numbers, underscore and hyphens under 'Org' columns. Output under 'Org' should be `ddc systems` and so on.

```
  Name      Org
0   abc   14_ddc_-_systems
1   sdc   14_ddc_-_systems
2   csc   14_ddd_-_systems
3   rdc   23_kbf_org
4   rfc   23_kbf_org
```

I tried below to remove numbers but it's not working ..

```
s = sheet1['Org'].head()
s = s.replace('\d+\s', '')
```

Any help will be appreciated.!

Comment: there is also the `TRIM` and `CLEAN` functions that may assist

Comment: @ForwardEd: How can I use this function on DataFrams

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.replace` with regex.

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Org": ["14_ddc_-_systems", "14_ddc_-_systems", "23_kbf_org"]})
df["New"] = df["Org"].str.replace(r"[^a-zA-Z ]+", " ").str.strip()
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                Org          New
0  14_ddc_-_systems  ddc systems
1  14_ddc_-_systems  ddc systems
2        23_kbf_org      kbf org
```